# python program to combine two files (that have wordcount) and issue a ratio

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python function that manipulates some data for me.
I have two text files that look like this:

Text file1:

```
   89 man
   32 is
   22 the
    3 best
```

Text file2:

```
  54 man
  43 dog
  34 best
  13 dude
```

I need to create some type of function that does `textfile1` ratio to `textfile2` for the words. Note that some words dont appear in both, but they should not be excluded, as they are needed for analysis. I do not know how to do this part of my analysis. The files have thousands of lines, and basic bash scripting will not get you so far, unfortunately.

Comment: Are the numbers important as well?

Comment: the numbers represent the wordcount, the textfiles are the result of a basic bash wordcount using tr , uniq and sort. Im trying to differentiate a uniqe wordcount between two topics.

Comment: I don't see why bash wouldn't be able to do everything.

Comment: @NullUserException well if you have an idea pls share :)

Comment: What have you got so far? Is there any particular problem regarding using Python? All I see is a general problem statement. Just create an algorithm and try implementing it in Python. If you run into any issues, then ask specific question regarding that.

Comment: And what exactly should the ratio be when a word does not appear in both files?  What would it mean to not exclude those words?

Comment: if a word does not appear in both files, it should just stay in the list without a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your problem is that your want to do the ratio of the numbers when you found them in both files, otherwise just print their original values. You can do something like this:

```
lines1 = [i.split() for i in open('tmp.txt').readlines()]
values,keys = zip(*lines1)
dict1 = dict( zip(keys,values) )
lines2 = [i.split() for i in open('tmp2.txt').readlines()]
values,keys = zip(*lines2)
dict2 = dict( zip(keys,values) )
dict3 = {}
for k1,v1 in dict1.items():
    v2 = dict2.get(k1)
    if v2:
        dict3[k1] = str(float(v1)/float(v2))
    else:
        dict3[k1] = v1
for k2,v2 in dict2.items():
    if not dict3.get(k2):
        dict3[k2] = v2
out = open('output.txt','w')
out.writelines(['%s\t%s\n' %\
    (k[0],dict3[k[0]]) for k in sorted(dict3.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])])
out.close()
```

Comment: yes thats brilliant :)

Comment: the only thing i'd see added is the ratio's being listed in order from largest to smallest, but im already extremely happy with this one.

Comment: @RHK-S8 You can easily change that when writing `dict3` to the output file. You can toggle the question as accepted if you find it fits your needs...

Comment: could u show in your code how to change that?

Comment: this might be too much too ask haha, but would python offer a solution to finding the middle 20 numbers? (not the top, nor bottom, but the middle)

Comment: yes, it can, but this extra is worth creating another question, you can refer to this one you already created when preparing the question